# Input shape for Conv 1D

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

I am trying to use Conv1D to classify malware based on an 1D array of data.

The shape of the X_train is (7200, 1000).
The shape of the Y_train is (1800, 1000).
The shape of X_test is (7200, 1).
The shape of Y_test(1800, 1).

I have tried doing

```
model.add(Conv1D(5, 5, input_shape=(X_train[1], 1)))
```

Does anyone know what input shape I should change it to so it will fit my data?

Comment: your train samples don't match your test samples. check them again.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow's Conv1D doesn't have an "input_shape" attribute. Try adding an Input layer before this one. Also, that 1 after the "input_shape" would cause an error. You must mention the parameter name too.